# How to find and write inside an input tag with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I would like to change a value of a input tag that haves the value 20 to 110 in the website https://www.tradingview.com/chart/. How can I actually do that?(all of that using selenium python)
[image]
The value i would like to change it's MA Length inside Vol, you can acess that by clicking at Vol(20) right below Apple Inc - D - Cboe BZX at the top left part of the website.

Comment: Clicking `Vol(20)` doesn't brings up the popup. Any further steps involved? Possibly you need a set of valid credentials. Do you have a demo set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Locate the element you would like to interact with using your [favourite browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

   [image]
2. Choose an appropriate [Locator Strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) which will allow to uniquely match the element at the page
3. [Locate the element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)
4. Wrap the locating code into an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) this way [your test will be more robust and reliable](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)
5. Use [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) APIs to interact with elements

Example code:

```
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'format')]"))).click()
input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'innerInput')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=30", input)
```

Comment: I believe it's better to raise a new one

Comment: yeah, i was doing at that moment, i'll send u the link here

Comment: there it's! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158950/how-to-find-and-write-inside-an-input-tag-with-selenium-python-2